# CloudFlare not caching vBulletin php page serving image content

Tags: cache, cloudflare, vbulletin

I have signed up with CloudFlare and while it seems to work for some pages I cannot get a rule to work correctly with php pages serving images.

The page in question is: http://www.landcruiserclub.net/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=23999&d=1452806909&thumb=1

I have a rule which says for that exact pattern, cache everything. 
Every time I go to Web-Sniffer or inspect the local headers I receive I get CF-Cache-Status:MISS

Should it be able to cache pages like this?

Thanks
Crispin

Comment: That page sets headers preventing it from being cached. `Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT; Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0; Pragma: no-cache`

Comment: @ceejayoz - thanks for the reply. Where are you seeing this? The headers I can see says expiry 23 Jan 2017; I have a version which CloudFlare does nto cache - http://nocache.landcruiserclub.net/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=23999&d=1452806909&thumb=1

Comment: @ceejayoz - disregard. I can see them. Doh. Now, to find where VB hides them. I cannot see that in the file. Still digging. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: ok, I'm still confused. I don't see that the cache-control is stopping anything (now) and still getting a MISS from CF. https://redbot.org/?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnocache.landcruiserclub.net%2Fforums%2Fattachment.php%3Fattachmentid%3D23999%26d%3D1452806909%26thumb%3D1